# Pythonの実行の仕方がわからない

Tags: python, spyder

pythonを初めて3日目の初心者です。

これはキーエンスのロガーのサンプルプログラムです。
これをspyderで実行させたいのですが実行の仕方がわかりません。
`Sample1.py C:\NR-500Sample.xdt 0`をどこかに打てば実行できると予想していますが
どこに入力するのか、どのような形で入力するかわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。

```
import os
import sys
import time
import win32com.client

NR500_USB_ID_START = 0
NR500_USB_ID_END = 3
NRX100_USB_ID_START = 4
NRX100_USB_ID_END = 7
NRX100_LAN_ID_START = 8
NRX100_LAN_ID_END = 11

STATE_START_WAIT = 2
STATE_TRIGGER_WAIT = 3
STATE_RUN = 4
STATE_REPEAT_RUN = 5
STATE_PRE_TRIGGER = 6
STATE_POST_TRIGGER = 7
STATE_STOP_WAIT = 8
STATE_READ_WAIT = 10
STATE_PROCEDURE_WAIT = 12

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        show_help()
        return

    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    if not os.path.isfile(file_path):
        print("File not exist")
        return

    id = int(sys.argv[2])
    if NRX100_LAN_ID_START <= id and id <= NRX100_LAN_ID_END:
        if len(sys.argv) < 4:
            show_help()
            return

        ip = sys.argv[3].split('.')
        if len(ip) != 4:
            print("Illegal IP address")
            return

        port_number = 24682
        if 5 <= len(sys.argv):
            port_number = int(sys.argv[4])
            if port_number < 1025 or 65535 < port_number:
                print("Illegal port number")
                return

    wave_logger = win32com.client.Dispatch("WaveLoggerX.Application")
    wave_logger.Initialize()
    wave_logger.Visible = True

    id_result = wave_logger.SetIdentifier(id)
    if id_result != 0:
        print("Failed to set the device ID [error code: %d]" %id_result)
        return

    if NRX100_LAN_ID_START <= id and id <= NRX100_LAN_ID_END:
        lan_id = id - NRX100_LAN_ID_START
        config_result = wave_logger.SetLanConfig(
            lan_id, ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3], port_number)
        if config_result != 0:
            print("Failed to set LAN parameters [error code: %d]" %config_result)
            return

        connect_result = wave_logger.ConnectLan
        if connect_result != 0:
            print("Connection failed [error code: %d]" %connect_result)
            return

    open_result = wave_logger.OpenFile(file_path)
    if open_result != 0:
        print("File open error [error code: %d]" %open_result)
        return

    start_result = wave_logger.Start
    if start_result != 0:
        print("Starting acquisition failed [error code: %d]" %start_result)
        return

    document = wave_logger.GetActiveFile
    try:
        while is_running(wave_logger.GetState):
            print("\r"+"The amount of sampling data: " + str(document.GetDataCount) + 
                  " point (Press 'Ctrl + C' to stop acquisition)", end="")
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        wave_logger.Stop()
        while is_running(wave_logger.GetState):
            time.sleep(1)

    print("\r"+"The amount of sampling data: " + str(document.GetDataCount) + 
          " point (Press 'Ctrl + C' to stop acquisition)")
    print("Press Enter to exit")
    input()


def is_running(state):
    return state in {STATE_START_WAIT,
                     STATE_TRIGGER_WAIT,
                     STATE_RUN,
                     STATE_REPEAT_RUN,
                     STATE_PRE_TRIGGER,
                     STATE_POST_TRIGGER,
                     STATE_STOP_WAIT,
                     STATE_READ_WAIT,
                     STATE_PROCEDURE_WAIT}


def show_help():
    print("<Operation explanation>")
    print("Reads the specified setting file, "
          "confirms the connection, and starts acquisition")
    print()
    print("<How to use>")
    print("$ python Sample1.py <Settings file path> "
          "<Connection identifier> <IP address(option)> <port number(option)>")
    print("    [Settings file path]")
    print("    xcf, xdt, ycf, ydt, kdt File")
    print("    [Connection identifier]")
    print("    0 : NR-500 USB ID0")
    print("    1 : NR-500 USB ID1")
    print("    2 : NR-500 USB ID2")
    print("    3 : NR-500 USB ID3")
    print("    4 : NR-X100 USB ID0")
    print("    5 : NR-X100 USB ID1")
    print("    6 : NR-X100 USB ID2")
    print("    7 : NR-X100 USB ID3")
    print("    8 : NR-X100 LAN ID0")
    print("    9 : NR-X100 LAN ID1")
    print("    10: NR-X100 LAN ID2")
    print("    11: NR-X100 LAN ID3")
    print("    [IP address]")
    print("    IP address of the NRX-100 to be connected")
    print("    Must be specified in the case of "
          "Connection identifier is 8 to 11 (LAN Connection)")
    print()
    print("<Example>")
    print("Sample1.py C:\\NR-500Sample.xdt 0")
    print("Sample1.py C:\\NR-X100Sample.ydt 8 192.168.100.100 24682")
    print


main()
```

Comment: 「実行」ボタンを押せば良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 引数が必要なんでしたね。その場合は https://www.think-self.com/programming/python/spyder-argv/  が参考になりませんか？